# How to remove default "Application" module from ZF2 Skeleton Application

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I created a ZF2 REST web service, starting from the ZF2 Skeleton Application.
I've created my own module, with my routes and a view strategy of `ViewStrategyJson`.

What I want to do is to remove the default "Application" module, so that the only module in my application is my own custom module, for my REST service.

I tried removing "Application" from the list of modules in `application.config.php`, making this change:

```
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'RestModule',
),

'modules' => array(
    'RestModule',
),
```

However, when I do this, all requests to my REST module now give me this error:

```
Fatal error:
Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message:
'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "error";
resolver could not resolve to a file' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:499

Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(205): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(233): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(198): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(102): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#4 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View in /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php** on line 499
```

I feel like I must be missing something, somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.
I would love some help/suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZF2 Skeleton Application provides some basic bootstrapping operations in Module.php's [onBootstrap()](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/Module.php#L17-L22) method such as attaching `$eventManager` instance to **ModuleRouteListener**, also represents some basic initial settings in [module.config.php](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php).

Don't forget to do same things in your RestModule before removing `Application` module.

If you migrated the `view_manager` settings from Application module's `module.config.php` to your RestModule's one too, make sure that it has three important keys related with error cases:

```
'not_found_template'   => 'error/404',
'exception_template'   => 'error/index',
'template_map' => array('
    'layout/layout'  => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
    'error/404'      => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
    'error/index'    => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
```

Since this keys represents view paths to correctly render exceptions and other erros, you have to move `Application/view/error` and `Application/view/layout` folders too into your RestModule or change these settings to suit your needs.

After these minor details, there is nothing wrong with the removing the Application module which provided by skeleton app.